# Set VBScript Variable with Unknown Type

Tags: types, vbscript

VBScript has two syntaxes for setting a variable

Primitives such as String and Integer are set as

```
primitive_var = 3
```

While objects are set as

```
Set my_object = some_object
```

I have a function call that could return either.  I can check for the type as follows

```
If VarType(f(x, y)) = vbObject Then
  Set result = f(x, y)
Else
  result = f(x, y)
End If
```

However this wastes a function call.  How can I do this with only one call to f?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Sub that assigns to a variable, using Set for objects:

```
Option Explicit

' returns regexp or "pipapo" (probably a design error,
' should be two distinct functions)
Function f(x)
  If x = 1 Then
     Set f = New RegExp
  Else
     f = "pipapo"
  End If
End Function

' assigns val to var nam, using Set for objects
' ByRef to emphasize manipulation of var nam
Sub assign(ByRef nam, val)
  If IsObject(val) Then
     Set nam = Val
  Else
     nam = Val
  End If
End Sub

Dim x
assign x, f(1) : WScript.Echo TypeName(x)
assign x, f(0) : WScript.Echo TypeName(x)
```

output:

```
cscript 27730273.vbs
IRegExp2
String
```

but I would prefer to have two distinct functions instead of one f().